# Get Rows Values with unique id in Room Database Android

Tags: android, database, android-room

I am going to get row values from Room Database with unique IDs and values of the "Product" Column.

I have ProductDao and Product Database and Product Class model also.

But I don't know how to set the function which gets row values from the Product Database.

Filter Condition is Price values and Shoe Category.

The category is "Shoes" and Value is much than 30 USD and less than 50 USD.

Category == "Shoes" && Value >= 30 && Value < 50

Please help me with how to make the function that gets row values that satisfy the condition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given the PRODUCT table, you must create a @Dao interface and declare a query function like the following:

```
@Dao
interface ProductDao {

    @Query("select * from PRODUCT where category = :c and value < :v")
    suspend fun getProducts(c: String, v: Double): List<Product>
}
```

You can use LievData and declare the same function like the following:

```
@Query("select * from PRODUCT where category=:c and value < :v")
fun getProduct(c: String, v: Double): LiveData<List<Product>>
```

The function parameters replace the placeholders in the query and *getProducts* will return the list of products whith category equal to the parameter '*c*' and value less than parameter '*v*'. Better if you also create a Repository. If you use Livedata do not declare the function as

> suspend

or you'll get a compilation error. In this case LiveData do not need a suspend function.

See Room documentation for more details.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, @Sergiob.
I am very appreciative of your kindness helps.

I didn't hear about LiveData before.
I think LiveData is a very good method to run my functions.
Can you please give me the link or doc about LiveData?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Look at here: https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/livedata